# How to test how much color information is in an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

I have two images. One is compressed and another is raw. The compressed image is lower quality and therefor has less information in it than the raw. I understand I could look at the size of the file, but I would like to do this in openCV python. How can I confirm which image has more information/higher quality in OpenCV?

Comment: Here the colorspaces managed by OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab. How are you opening a raw image in OpenCV?

Comment: @iGian I suspect that the OP is not referring to a [raw image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format), but simply an uncompressed image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that by the raw image you refer to the original uncompressed image and not the `raw` format.
I couldn't find anything useful in OpenCV but you can use PIL and check the image attached info

```
>>> from PIL import Image

>>> im1 = Image.open('1.jpeg') # raw uncompressed image
>>> print(im1.info)
{'jfif': 257, 'jfif_version': (1, 1), 'jfif_unit': 0, 'jfif_density': (1, 1)}

>>> im2 = Image.open('2.jpeg') # compressed image
>>> print(im2.info)
{'jfif': 257, 'jfif_version': (1, 1), 'jfif_unit': 0, 'jfif_density': (1, 1), 'progressive': 1, 'progression': 1}
```

I checked the image info and it shows the difference between the two. The compressed image uses progressive compression and it can be seen in the attributes. Use can use this info to differentiate the two types!